# How to iterate a custom function to columns with object data type in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a custom barplot function called `label_bar`, I want to do the following

1. loop `label_bar` through categorical(object data type)column in a dataframe
2. export the plots as a pdf file  - 2 plots per page

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)

import plotly.express as px
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



# custom function to visualize the barplot

def label_bar(data, feature, perc=False, n=None):
    """
    Barplot with percentage at the top

    data: dataframe
    feature: dataframe column
    perc: whether to display percentages instead of count (default is False)
    n: displays the top n category levels (default is None, i.e., display all levels)
    """

    total = len(data[feature])  # length of the column
    count = data[feature].nunique()
    if n is None:
        plt.figure(figsize=(count + 2, 6))
    else:
        plt.figure(figsize=(n + 2, 6))

    plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=15)
    ax = sns.countplot(
        data=data,
        x=feature,
        palette="Paired",
        order=data[feature].value_counts().index[:n],
    )

    for p in ax.patches:
        if perc == True:
            label = "{:.1f}%".format(
                100 * p.get_height() / total
            )  # percentage of each class of the category
        else:
            label = p.get_height()  # count of each level of the category

        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2  # width of the plot
        y = p.get_height()  # height of the plot

        ax.annotate(
            label,
            (x, y),
            ha="center",
            va="center",
            size=12,
            xytext=(0, 5),
            textcoords="offset points",
        )  # annotate the percentage

    plt.show()  # show the plot


# Generate dataset
import pandas as pd

data = {'pet': ['cat', 'leopard', 'dog', 'goat', 'goat','cat','lizard','rabbit','lizard','goat','fish','cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'goat', 'goat','cat','lizard','rabbit','lizard'],
        'vet_cost': [1200, 150, 300, 450, 200,550,750,800,350,150,320,150, 300, 450, 200,550,750,800,350,150],
        'x_region':['R1','R3','R1','R5','R2','R5','R1','R1','R6','R1','R1','R3','R1','R5','R2','R5','R1','R1','R7','R1'],
        'x_class':['T1','T1','T2','T3','T5','T5','T5','T0','T5','T4','T1','T6','T2','T3','T7','T8','T5','T8','T5','T4'],
        'x_diet':['D1','D3','D1','D5','D2','D4','D4','D1','D6','D1','D1','D3','D1','D5','D2','D5','D1','D1','D7','D1'],
        'y_region':['Y1','Y3','Y1','Y5','Y2','Y5','Y1','Y1','Y6','Y1','Y1','Y3','Y1','Y5','Y2','Y5','Y1','Y1','Y7','Y1'],
        'y_class':['Z1','Z1','Z2','Z3','Z5','Z5','Z5','Z0','Z5','Z4','Z1','Z6','Z2','Z3','Z7','Z8','Z5','Z8','Z5','Z4'],
        'y_diet':['A1','A3','A1','A5','A2','A4','A4','A1','A6','A1','A1','A3','A1','A5','A2','A5','A1','A1','A7','A1'],}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

### I want to apply the function to columns with object data types 

df.select_dtypes('object')


###########This where I need help#############################################################3


#I want to loop through 'object' columns and export the plots (2 per page) to a pdf 


label_bar(df, "pet", perc=True)

label_bar(df, "x_region", perc=True)

label_bar(df, "x_class", perc=True)

label_bar(df, "x_diet", perc=True)

label_bar(df, "y_region", perc=True)

label_bar(df, "y_class", perc=True)

label_bar(df, "y_diet", perc=True)

# exporting as pdf

from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

for page in range(4):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(7,3)) 
    for j in range(3):
         i = page * 3 + j 
        #
        
        
    plt.savefig(path+'\{}.png'.format(str(b[i])),bbox_inches='tight',dpi=300)
    pdf.savefig(fig)
       
pdf.close()
```

Pls add comments to your code for better understanding. :)